# Why am I unable to install iCloud from MS store on windows 10?

Tags: icloud, windows, installation

I am trying to install iCloud for windows 10 from Microsoft App Store but it is not installing. When I click on the "Get" button of the iCloud on the Microsoft store page it changes color from blue to gray to blue again. Nothing happens. No software is downloaded or installed.

I tried multiple times on different laptops. One had previous version of iCloud installed and other laptop was clean.

Old version of iCloud got installed via download from Apple site but it is not working properly: photos are not getting downloaded on the computer.

It would be great if you can help me installing latest version of iCloud on windows 10.

Comment: "it is not installing" means when I click on the "Get" button of the iCloud on the Microsoft store page it changes color from blue to gray to blue again.Nothing happens. No software is downloaded or installed.

Comment: yes. old version of icloud got installed but it is not working properly... photos are not getting downloaded on the computer.

Comment: iCloud for windows 10 requires outlook on your system which I dont have...

Comment: When logged into your Win10 machine, are you using a local account or a Microsoft Account.  In other words, can you log into Microsoft ID with the *same* username/password that you do for your computer?

Comment: Did you try "Apple Software Update"?

Comment: @Allan Yes I am using Microsoft account.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes, I have Apple Software Update installed.

Comment: @SacrificialEquation: I assume if the iCloud software was not up to date, then running Apple Software Update should find a update to install. I just installed Windows 10 on a Mac, then downloaded and installed iCloud from the Apple website [Download iCloud for Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204283). Note: When installing, I had to click on a shield icon that appeared at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: All softwares are up to date. Download from the apple website works. But that is not the latest software for windows 10. You have to download from Microsoft Store. Microsoft Store is giving the problem. Which is strange as leading companies are involved.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230 These are the requirements for iCloud for windows:

> - Microsoft Windows 10
> - iCloud for Windows 7 or iCloud for Windows 10(Windows 10 May 2019 Update or later is recommended for iCloud for Windows 10.)
> - iTunes 12.7
> - Outlook 2010 - Outlook 2016 (Outlook 2010 Personal Edition isn't supported.)
> - Firefox 45 or later, Google Chrome 54 or later (desktop mode only), Microsoft Edge, or Opera

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204283 One can try manual download if MS store is not helping.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201391 Setting up, using, uninstalling etc.

Comment: I have everything except outlook. However Microsoft Store recommended requirements says windows 10 is sufficient. Moreover , Microsoft Store says the iCloud can be installed on my device. But it is not installing.

Comment: sorry but this answer is kind of useless. I have the same problem when I click get and nothing happens. I don't have iTunes though, but in that guide about iCloud they simply say "install iCloud from MS Store" and don't say anything like "you must have iTunes in order to be able to install iCloud".